# Use hyperlink to navigate to another tab in Navigation form

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I'm creating a ticketing system. I have a tab to create a ticket, resolve/edit a ticket, and to search the ticket list (a continuous form displaying results based on my search criteria). What I ultimately want to do is create a link from the record on the Search Ticket List tab that opens up the record in the Resolve/Edit ticket tab. But before I can begin tackling the specifics of that, I need to know:

**How in the world do I create a link from one tab to another??**

They all seem to use the same subform, so it's not like I can use that as a reference to point my link there. I'm fairly new to access (I've just been muddling along with the help of Google and YouYube tutorials, so be gentle :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have solved this issue. I used...

```
doCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "name of form that is showing up as the subform", "name of navigation form.NavigationSubform"
```

Now on to the hard part: creating links to specific records.